# Merge methods to one hash, through method chaining

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a class which is generating queries for a db:

They should concatenated, so I do not repeat my code for a query (DRY).

I thought I could do something like this:

ruby

```
class Blah < ActiveRecord::Base
  def no_scope
    {scope: false}
  end

  def for_user(user_id)
    {user_id: user_id}
  end
end
```

Now my query

```
    Blah.no_scope.for_user(1)
```

RESULT SHOULD BE A **HASH**:

```
    {user_id: 1, scope: false}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to achieve this?

```
class Blah < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :no_scope, -> { where(scope: false) }
  scope :for_user, -> (id) { where(user_id: id) }
end

Blah.no_scope.for_user(1) #  where(scope: false, user_id: 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create scopes.

```
class Blah < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :no_scope, -> {all}
  scope :for_user, -> (user_id) {where(user_id: user_id)} 

end


Blah.no_scope.for_user(1) #  where(user_id: 1)
```

See also [scopes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html)

Answer (score 0):

To give the result as a real Hash instead of a Activerecord relation, you do it like this

```
class Blah < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :no_scope, ->{where(scope: false)}
  scope :for_user, ->(id){where(user_id: id)} # no space in ->(id)
end

# give results as an array of hashes
Blah.no_scope.for_user(1).map { |e| {scope: e.scope, user_id: e.user_id} }
```

gives

```
[{"scope"=>false, "user_id"=>1}]
```